# Eclipse C/C++ (CDT) add -l option (linking math module) gcc -lm

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, linker, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to have eclipse on linux (Ubuntu) link the math module.
Normally I would link with gcc -lm.  How do I get eclipse to add this?
Is it in library paths under Project->Properties? Where does the math module reside on a linux Ubuntu system?

Comment: The math *library* is just `libm`/`-lm` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Somewhere along this path: Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings, then under the Tools tab: GCC Linker->Libraries

As for where it is in the system, usually /usr/lib/libm.so.

FYI, this is all true of my system, but may differ slightly on yours for any number of reasons. Shouldn't be hard to adjust if needed.

Comment: I found the -l option under C/C++ build => Settings => GCC C Linker => Libraries

Comment: @loan I am facing same problem and I found "libm.so" But I don't know what to do next ??? plz guide

Comment: You can easily add the character `m` instead of the path. It works for me. It cause the parameter `-lm`

Answer (score 7):

Go to **Project** and select **Properties**. 
Expand **C/C++ Build** and choose **Settings**. 
Under the **Tool settings** tab expand **GCC Linker** and select **Libraries**. 
At the right of the window, add a library named **m** at **Libraries (-l)**.

Comment: Where do you do that in eclipse 2019-12? My C/C++ project is using cmake + ninja. Do I have to recreate the project? Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in workspace preferences, C/C++, Build, Environment doesn't work.