# Why Eclipse CDT does not automatically link libm.so?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I wrote a program containing functions from `math.h` and clicked on `Build All` in Eclipse CDT in Ubuntu. No binary was generated. When I built my program from the terminal including the `-lm` flag, it worked. My guess is that Eclipse CDT did not include the `-lm` flag when building the source code.

So assuming my guess is correct, why doesn't Eclipse do this by itself? Do I have to change a setting or is there an obstacle that prevents Eclipse from looking at the code and including any necessary libraries in compilation? Or if my assumption is wrong, what might caused Eclipse to not generate a binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse C/C++ (CDT) add -l option (linking math module) gcc -lm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480013/eclipse-c-c-cdt-add-l-option-linking-math-module-gcc-lm)