# Fixing undefined reference to dlopen() and dlcose()

Tags: c++, linux, g++, dlopen

I have created a simple C++ application. I can compile it, and it works fine. But now I need to load the library dynamically, and I have added *dlfnc.h* to my project and added some more code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *mylib;
int eret;

using namespace std;

int main() {

    mylib = dlopen("mylib.so", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
    eret = dlclose(mylib);

    cout << "!!!Hello, World!!!" << endl; // Prints !!!Hello, World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
cd ~/workspace/LinuxGcc/src
g++ LinuxGcc.cpp
```

And I got a compilation error:

```
/tmp/ccxTLiGY.o: In function `main':
LinuxGcc.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `dlopen'
LinuxGcc.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`dlfcn.h` exist in `/usr/include/`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You added the `.h`, but you also need to link the library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc

Comment: Just define suitable functions and it will link: `extern "C" { void dlopen() {} void dlclose() {} }` Alternative read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and it will tell you what library(-ies) you need to add ( the latter is probably more work but also more likely to result in a working program).

Comment: The answers are completely missing the *why*. For example, thus limited use in a similar situation with a different library. Or this library could be special in some way. Or where is the library physically located (in case it is missing or in an unexpected location) and what is its actual file name?

Comment: [Part of the why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641768/adding-c-external-library-in-visual-studio-code#comment99890420_56641768).

Answer (score 14):

From [dlopen(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

> ```
>    Link with -ldl.
> ```

so

```
g++ LinuxGcc.cpp -ldl
```

will be OK.

Comment: This works fine! I have the same project in eclipse. How to tell Eclipse that it must link this lib?

Comment: @vico This is an IDE issue, google for "Eclipse C++ link flags" gives me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480013/eclipse-c-c-cdt-add-l-option-linking-math-module-gcc-lm

Answer (score 5):

The solution is very simple. Add the [-ldl](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l) flag for linking.

Answer (score 1):

In case of the [Bazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazel_(software)) build system, *linkopts = ['-ldl']*.